# How can I restrict most/all network access to user on specific Windows machine?

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

Update: I took a network based approach here instead of permissions. The testlab laptop is now on its own subnet and only certain vpn users able to connect to it.

We have a user with VPN access to a network but restricted to only the IP of a specific test lab entry point laptop. Once they have remoted in, they should not be able to make connections to other resources on the network. Is there a way to accomplish this restriction through group policy, firewall, etc on the laptop (Windows 10) and/or Active Directory? I can setup as local or domain user, which ever is necessary to implement this restriction.

Comment: This is something that should be done at the network level. IF the client computer were in AD and under your management, it may be possible to have firewall rules that block/allow access for only that computer but that's the wrong way to do it.

Comment: I was on the fence about adjusting our network to accomplish this. In the end I setup a new subnet and firewall rule for special vpn group to provide secure access. Looks like we should be good now.